# How to find a value for a specific key in python

Tags: python, for-loop, dictionary, key-value

```
import requests
import json

# initial message
message = "if i can\'t let it go out of my mind"

# split into list
split_message = message.split()

def decrementList(words):
    for w in [words] + [words[:-x] for x in range(1,len(words))]:
        url = 'http://ws.spotify.com/search/1/track.json?q='
        request = requests.get(url + "%20".join(w))

        json_dict = json.loads(request.content)
        num_results = json_dict['info']['num_results']
        if num_results > 0:
            num_removed = len(words) - len(w)

            #track_title = ' '.join(words)

            track_title = "If I Can't Take It with Me"

            for value in json_dict.items():
                if value == track_title:
                    print "match found"

            return num_removed, json_dict


num_words_removed, json_dict = decrementList(split_message)
```

In the code below, I am trying to match the name of a song to my search query.  In this particular query, the song will not match, but I have added a variable that will match the song for the returned query. The for loop at the end of the function is supposed to match the track title variable, but I can't figure out why it isn't working.  Is there a simple way to find all values for a known key?  In this case, the key is "name"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to search for the track title, within the `tracks` dictionary. So, just change your code like this

```
for value in json_dict["tracks"]:
    if value["name"] == track_title:
```

it would print

```
match found
```